# Trim an environmental variable in makefile

Tags: makefile, user-input

I maintain a project which provides [makefile for Arduino](https://github.com/sudar/Arduino-Makefile)

There is a master (common) makefile and the users create a small makefile where they set certain environmental variables and then include the master makefile.

A typical makefile looks likes this

```
# Arduino Make file. Refer to https://github.com/sudar/Arduino-Makefile 

BOARD_TAG    = atmega328
ARDUINO_PORT = /dev/ttyACM*

include $(ARDMK_DIR)/arduino-mk/Arduino.mk
```

Recently, I was [debugging a bug](https://github.com/sudar/Arduino-Makefile/issues/57) and then found out that if there is an additional space at the end of `BOARD_TAG` environmental variable, then it results in an error, which is not very intuitive for someone to fix.

My initial thought was to fix it by trimming the environmental variable inside the makefile.  But on second thought I was not sure whether that is the correct way to fix this issue.

So my question is what is the recommended way to fix these kind of user input issues in makefile? Should I try to trim it or is there an alternate way to fix this?

Comment: Yes, it seems reasonable, and yes, there are alternatives. You can trim it by means of the [strip](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions) function.

Comment: Is it possible to trim the variable and store the results in the same variable? I am getting `Recursive variable `BOARD_TAG' references itself (eventually)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To trim the variable "in place", just treat it as a [simply expanded variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Flavors):

```
BOARD_TAG = atmega328

BOARD_TAG := $(strip $(BOARD_TAG))
```

If you use "=", it's a *recursive expanded* variable, so any expression on the right (e.g. `$(strip ...)`) will not be expanded until the variable itself is evaluated; if you try to put the variable itself on the right, Make warns you that that expression can't be evaluated because it goes into an infinite loop.

If you use ":=", it becomes a *simply expanded* variable; Make expands the right-hand side then and there, assigns the result to the variable and that's that.